# Undefined reference to vtbel

Tags: c++

Im trying to implement a object oriented program, but i cant compile barco.cpp. This is the message on terminal

```
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
/tmp/ccCcV82C.o: In function `Barco::Barco()':
barco.cpp:(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `vtable for Barco'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried on putting barco.cpp and barco.hpp on another folder but it didnt work.

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv1Jq.png)

```
#ifndef BOAT_HPP
#define BOAT_HPP

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Boat {
  private:
    int size;
    public:
      virtual void skill();
     Boat();

     int get_size();
     void set_size(int size);

};

#endif

\\boat.cpp

#include "boat.hpp"
#include <iostream>

Boat::Boat(){
  size = 0;

}
int Boat::get_size(){
  return size;
}
void Boat::set_size(int size){
  this->size = size;
}
```

Comment: You missed to specify a `main()` function where the executable should enter maybe? Post a [mcve] reproducing your problem as required here in order to get helped.

Comment: Where is `habilidade` defined?

Comment: Hi Lucia, and welcome to Stack Overflow! We need more details to help you. How did you define your main function? Is the only problem the error message? Additionally, we'll be able to help you a lot easier if you include your code as plain text rather than a screenshot. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55669959/edit) to add relevant information and details. Good luck!

Comment: Also, don't post pictures of your code. Post your code directly into the questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have a virtual function in the header which is not implemented in the CPP:

```
virtual void skill();
```